# Set field in setter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my model i have some validations like this:

```
validates :text, presence: true, unless: :skip_fehler
```

I set `skip_fehler` for the particular instance within my controller:

```
@user.create(skip_fehler: params['skip_fehler'], text: ..
```

Bascially my code worked when i had in my model:

```
attr_accessor :skip_fehler
```

The only problem i noticed was that when the `@user.skip_fehler` was set to `""` the validation was also skipped.

**I want to avoid that behaviour** So i tried to change `accessor` to `reader`:

```
  attr_reader :skip_fehler
```

And i wrote my own setter method:

```
  def skip_fehler=(value)
    if value && value != "" 
      self.skip_fehler = true
    else
      self.skip_fehler = false
    end
  end
```

But now, i get this **Error**: `stack level too deep`

I suppose because within `skip_fehler=(value)` i call `self.skip_fehler = true`!

How do i have to change my code? So that when `skip_fehler` is set in the controller to `""` its set to `false` in the model? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `write_attribute` instead of assigning. This way the value gets written to the internal representation of attributes directly.

```
write_attribute(:skip_fehler, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
attr_reader :skip_fehler

def skip_fehler=(value)
  @skip_fehler = value.present?
end
```

That work, because `attr_reader :skip_fehler` is a shortcut for:

```
def skip_fehler
  @skip_fehler
end
```

and `value.present?` does the same than `!value.nil? && value != ""`

Answer (score 0):

Rails validators accept Procs for the :if and :unless parameters.
This means you can declare your validator like this:

```
validates :text, 
    presence: true, 
    unless: Proc.new { |model| model.skip_fehler.present? }
```

The validator will call your proc with your model. present? returns false for an empty string, so your validator will not ignored in that case.